# How do we fixed the button at the top on Window scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to fix the button on top when we scroll the window ,as soon as the button reach on the top then to be fixed, please need your help, i am using javascript code for this or if you have suitable code related to javascript or jquery then please suggest me,

i am showing a snapshot that clear you that what i want to do in this images,

[image is here please click to see clearly my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHIV3.jpg)

`This is my button code`

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary HELPLINE NUMBER " id="NUMBER">HELPLINE NUMBER</a>
```

and 
`This is javascript code what i have tried:`

```
<script>

window.onscroll= function(){ myfunc(); }

var location_v=document.getElementById("NUMBER");
var pixtop=location_v.offsetTop;

function myfunc()
{


    if(window.pageYOffset >= pixtop )
    {

        //var a=document.getElementById('NUMBER');
                location_v.classList.add('stick');

    }
    else
    {
        a.classList.remove('stick');
        }

}


</script>
```

and the css code is below:

```
.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and please also don't forget to tell me what i am missing, if you have any conceptual javascript or jquery code...

Comment: `.stick{ position:sticky;top:0;}`  unless you need to support antiquated broken browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that can do the trick for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {      
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 90) {
      $('#NUMBER').addClass('stick');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 91) {
      $('#NUMBER').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

And what it does is on each scroll event it checks the scrolling position from top of a `window` and using `if` check it either adds or removes your pre-made `stick` class. But of course you have to chose your own numbers in this `if` check.

I have also played around with a code snippet, so you can see how it works

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {      
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
      $('#NUMBER').addClass('stick');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 11) {
      $('#NUMBER').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="NUMBER">Press me</button>
```